# Is there a standard mapping between ISO country code to its geo area?

Tags: iso, country-codes

For example, China (CHN) maps to APAC, and US maps to NA. I couldn't find any mapping through internet, I guess it's because there's no authoritative mapping for a country? A country could map to multiple regions, with geographical level, or political or economical level. e.g., CHN belongs to Asia, and APAC, too.

Any help or suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous standards for regional groupings of countries, so you would have to definitively choose which one you're interested in before you'll be able to find a mapping with ISO country code. For example...

[United Nations geoscheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Regional_Groups)

[United Nations Regional Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Regional_Groups)

[World Bank regions](http://www.worldbank.org/en/about/annual-report/regions)

Comment: that being said, the [countrycode r-pkg](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode) and its [underlying data](https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode/blob/master/data/countrycode_data.csv) provides a mapping between numerous country code schemes (like and including ISO 3166-1) and various regional grouping schemes